# Magento 2.3.5-p1 - Elasticsearch index not found

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

Our Magento website has a number of stores:

[image: Stores]

When I run `bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext` it times out after about 4-5 hours and never completes.  Here is what I can see when I run `/_cat/indices?v`

[image: Elasticsearch Indices]

So if I'm understanding this correctly, should there be a magento2_product_`x`_v`x` for every store? It looks like it's reindexed store1 9 times and store4 only ever gets to 65000 / 94324.  Stores 5, 6 and 7 don't exist and that would explain this error in the log:

```
Elasticsearch index not found. Run "bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext".
```

Is the issue that there are 2 magento_product_3 versions?

I'm clueless when it comes to Elasticsearch so any help interpreting the Elasticsearch output is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this by indexing 1 store at a time, which was done by overriding `public function executeByDimensions` within `Fulltext.php`

While not a long term solution, the website is now displaying all products in each category for each store.  If I figure out a better solution I'll update this post.